# How to perform authentication in a java web service using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, web-services

I have created this webservice in netbeans ide
I would like basic Authorization before client make any request. The service works fine but how do I Pass username and password from client using httpconnection class.
Here is my webservice.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;

@WebService(serviceName = "SampleWs")
public class SampleWs implements CreateCustomer {
    @Resource
    WebServiceContext wsctx;
    @Override
    public String createCustomer(Customers customer) {
        String resp="Access Denied";

        MessageContext mctx = wsctx.getMessageContext();

        Map http_headers = (Map) mctx.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS);
        String username = (String) http_headers.get("username");//should come from the client request
        String password = (String) http_headers.get("password");//should come from the client request
        if(username.equals("admin")&&password.equals("pass"))
        {
            resp="Authenticated";
        }
       return resp;

    }


}
//interface 
import javax.jws.WebMethod;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface CreateCustomer {
    @WebMethod    String createCustomer(Customers customer);
}
//model class
public class Customers {    
    private int id;
    private String fname;
    private String sname;
    private String gender;
    private String email;

     //getters and setters
}
```

And here is my client

```
public class SampleClient {

    private static final String url_ = "http://localhost:7001/SampleWs/SampleWs";



    public static String testAuthorisation() {
        String varresp = "";
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            String req = getSoapRequestXMl();
            String name = "adm";
            String password = "pass";

            String authString = name + ":" + password;

            byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());//apache lib for Base64
            String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);

            URL url = new URL(url_);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
            //conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);

            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            writer.write(req);
            writer.flush();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                answer.append(line);
            }
            writer.close();
            reader.close();
            varresp = answer.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            varresp = "!" + e;

        } finally {
            return varresp;
        }

    }

    private static String getSoapRequestXMl() {
        String request = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                + "    <soap:Header/>\n"
                + "    <soap:Body>\n"
                + "        <ns1:hello xmlns:ns1=\"http://ws.ecs.co/\">\n"
                + "            <name>\n"
                + "                <email>testemail@yahoo.com</email>\n"
                + "                <fname>Firsname</fname>\n"
                + "                <gender>Male</gender>\n"
                + "                <id>23</id>\n"
                + "                <sname>Nemuga</sname>\n"
                + "            </name>\n"
                + "        </ns1:hello>\n"
                + "    </soap:Body>\n"
                + "</soap:Envelope>";

        return request;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of your code in client side will add the required header for Basic authentication

```
conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
```

In server side, you need to read the "Authorization" header and extract the content

```
Map<String, List<String>> headers= (Map<String, List<String>>) messageContext
                .get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS);

//The header "Basic base64(user:password)
String authHeader = headers.get("Authorization").get(0);

//Remove "Basic "
String authtoken = authorizationHeader.split(" ")[1];

//Decode base64 and read username and password 
String token = new String(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(authtoken));
String tokenS[] = token.split(":");
String username = tokenS [0];
String password = tokenS [1];
```

I have not tested all the code, but it should work

Comment: when I run your code am getting java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL

Comment: My code extracts the username and password from http header, it does not perform the authorization itself. Is the client sending the header?  Is the server receiving it? Show the server logs with the values of authHeader, authToken, username and password variables

Comment: No Logs at all on the server

Comment: I can't code it for you. You need to add some logs or debug the server to see what it is happening.

Comment: MessageContext messageContext = wsctx.getMessageContext();
        Map<String, List<String>> headers= (Map<String, List<String>>) messageContext
                .get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS);
        System.out.println("headers:"+headers); I tried outputting header map but not output at all

Comment: That line will not print the content. Only the hash of the object. But if you do not see anything in the standard output means this code is not being invoked at all. You have a distint issue not related with this code. You need to learn first some concepts about how to debug a server. I cant help you

Comment: when I put this request property    conn.setRequestProperty ("Auth", " " + authStringEnc); I get this output from the server headers:{Accept=[text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2], Auth=[YWRtOnBhc3M=], Connection=[keep-alive], Content-Length=[1036], Content-Type=[text/xml], Host=[localhost:7001], User-Agent=[Java/1.8.0_131]}

Comment: `Auth=[YWRtOnBhc3M=]` is not correct. It should be `Authorization=[Basic YWRtOnBhc3M=]`. Use the code I provided in the answer `conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);`

Comment: When I put this in client conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc); its not working no output in server and client get error 401. Is there harm of using    conn.setRequestProperty ("Auth", " " + authStringEnc);?

Comment: You said _I would like basic Authorization_ Basic authorization requires a "Authorization" header and a "Basic " word. Of course you can use a custom header, but then it is not "Basic Authorization". If you get 401 when you are calling server with "Authorization" header, it means that somebody is intercepting your request and responding. Are you using a proxy or a Weblogic server?

Comment: I am using weblogic Server

Comment: Weblogic is capturing your requests. See [Disabling Authentication on Oracle WebLogic Server](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41509_01/pt852pbh2/eng/psbooks/tfee/chapter.htm?File=tfee/htm/tfee12.htm)

Comment: Thanks a lot that was the problem I can comfortably accept your answer